# Fetching second word from a string in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, substr

I need to get the second word of each name in a column, I did my research about substr and instr, but I think I have a logical error, I simply cannot point it out.

```
select substr(vendor_name,instr(vendor_name, ' ')+1) from vendors ORDER BY vendor_id asc;
```

[Here is my current output, the code works, but it does not do what I want it to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFull.png)

Comment: regexp_substr is your friend... much better than substr and instr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(vendor_name,
              INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,
              INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 2) - INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 1) - 1)
FROM vendors
ORDER BY vendor_id
```

To see how this works, take an example `vendor_name` of `Boeing Corporation Inc.`  In this case:

```
INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 1) = 7  = first occurrence of space
INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 2) = 19 = second occurrence of space
```

Now here is the call we are making to substring:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Boeing Corporation Inc.',
              7 + 1,
              19 - 7 - 1)
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Boeing Corporation Inc.', 8, 11) = 'Corporation'
```

Note that my answer assumes that there is a second space present in the `vendor_name` (and also a first space).  If you expect complex data in this column, you might want to use a regular expression instead.

Comment: Ok great, that works, thank you very much, but I dont understand the last part, where you subtract.

I understand that the first part you get the string, with the next word, +1 to remove the space.

But after that, I try the step by step input, and the ouput dosen't make sense, like how can it give me this [link](http://i.imgur.com/W66oy4N.png) when my input is this: 

`SELECT SUBSTR(vendor_name,INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 2))FROM vendors ORDER BY vendor_id;`

Comment: cause you need to add third parameter to Substr function to limit the length of string it extracts.  `INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 2) - INSTR(vendor_name, ' ', 1, 1) - 1` is length between 1st and 2nd spaces.

Comment: @AlexTonitoi Let me add an example, and you will see what is happening.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen wow, i understand now, i couldn't understand the occurence like this. I wish my teacher was as least 25% as good as you are in your explanation, thank you loads!

Comment: @AlexTonitoi Tell your teacher to get his rep higher on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and you're straight up savage, AMAZING!